# Where to put code to Redirect user back to page until predicate is true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

I wish to replicate similar functionality that ASP provides, that when a user is not authenticated, they are redirected to a specific page (the login page).

However, Instead of the login page, I wish to persistently send the user to a specific action on a controller until the user fills in a form to change their password for the first time when they ARE authenticated.

When they first log in, I am checking the following and redirecting them here accordingly:

```
if (user.HasChangedPassword())
{
    // This user hasn't changed their password to something more secure, send them to the page to change it
    return this.Redirect("Manage");
}
```

I would like to take this code out of my login code and have it checked site wide, so that the user is restricted to the single "Manage" action on my controller until they have set a secure password.

Please can you tell me where I could put this code so that it is effective site wide within my project?

The only thing I can think of is to check this in each of my controllers which seems very untidy.

Comment: Create an HTTP module http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).ASPX and plug it into your web.config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an action filter and register it as a global filter.

[ASP.NET MVC Action filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

[Example of registering filter globally](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)